# How to print out the entries of a Map into an html document

Tags: javascript, hashmap

Hi there I have the following code:

```
function showsaveobj(){
let patient = creatobj();
let befaktoren = patient.addfaktoren();
console.log(befaktoren);



let show = document.getElementById("show");

show.innerHTML = "Vorname: " + patient.vorname + "<br>Nachname: " + patient.nachname + "<br>" + (function() {for (let entry of befaktoren.entries()){return entry}})();

};
```

This last function is invoked when I press save inside the html document. It creates an object with a surname and a lastname and it has a method which creates a map out of the values the user  has entered into the form. The form has 24 values corresponding to the 24h of the day. So the map is 24 entries long. I want to print these entries into the html document as you can see above. It works fine with the name and the surname but when I use the for..of loop to write the single entries It only prints out the first entry of the map.
When I add

```
for (let x of befaktoren.entries()){console.log(x);}
```

The console shows me 24 Arrays with the key and the value inside. When I do the same thing inside the string with innerHtml it only writes the first array of the map into the document.
 I am doing something wrong here, but i cannot figure out what. After searching the web for several days now i hope someone here can help me. 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the `Map.entries()` method. `entries()` does not return an `iterable` object that you can traverse with a for loop, but instead it returns an `Iterator` that contains all the entries which you can then retrieve with the `next()` method.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

A `Map` itself is `iterable` so you can use your `for` loop on the map itself.
Despite that

your code:

```
someString + (function() {
  for (let entry of befaktoren.entries()) {
    return entry
  }
})()
```

will always put the first element only into your string.

instead do something like this:

```
var befaktorenFormatter = function(input) {
  let formattedString;
  // directly iterate over the input iterable
  for (let entry of input) {
    formattedString += entry;
  }
  // don't return the current entry, return the fully formatted string instead
  return formattedString;
}

show.innerHTML = "Vorname: " + patient.vorname + "<br>Nachname: " + patient.nachname + "<br>" + befaktorenFormatter(befaktoren);
```

`Map` has the convenience method `forEach` for iterating over its contents.
Also see: http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/map/foreach .
Instead of using a `for` loop you could also do something like this:

```
let befaktoren = new Map([['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'foo']]);

let befaktorenFormatter = function(input) {
  let formattedString;
  input.forEach(function(value, key) {
    formattedString += `${key}: ${value}<br>`;
  });
  return formattedString;
};

show.innerHTML = "Vorname: " + patient.vorname + "<br>Nachname: " + patient.nachname + "<br>" + befaktorenFormatter(befaktoren);
```

I hope that helped.

Comment: Hey man, thanks it helped a lot. The thing I still do not understand is that if write for (let x of befaktoren.entries()){console.log(x);} It logs all the entries as single arrays. Also when I write for (let x of befaktoren.entries()){document.write(x);} , js  writes all the entries into the html. So why doesn' t the for loop work with innerHTML,

Comment: To proof that i understood what you wrote,  "let formattedString" needs to be assigned an empty string to otherwise the first element of the returned string will be undefined. Thank You again very much. Without your help I wouldn't have solved this problem.